# No se dispara Evento OnKeyDown en formulario creado con CreateNew()

Tags: formularios, delphi

Consulta! Tengo un formulario que estoy creando en tiempo de ejecucion y no me captura los eventos **keyDown** y **keyUp**.

El asunto es que estoy realizando pruebas donde dibujo utilizando un formulario **FMX** y un formulario **VCL** para compararlos y de manera de aprendizaje. Estoy practicando y entendiendo como funcionan las unidades , herencia y demás.

Tengo la clase **TVCLForm** en una unidad aparte con todos los eventos **ONKEYDOWN**, **ONKEYUP**, implementados como cuando los realizo en diseño, pero sin haberlo hecho en tiempo de diseño.

En mi unidad principal  determino que tipo de formulario creo, si VCL o FMX. Los formularios se crean. Puedo dibujar en ellos, VCL en win32 y FMX con Directx , **pero necesito que me capturen las teclas y no lo estarían realizando.**
Otro tema también, es que estoy utilizando (**CreateNew**) , porque no quiero utilizar los DFM, ya que solo requiero crear un **FORM** vacio simple y sencillo, que solo capture teclas. Nada mas. Todo en codigo.

Unidad principal :

```
FormDisplay := TFormVcl.CreateNew(nil);
  FormDisplay.Width := xLimit; // 
  FormDisplay.Height := yLimit;
  FormDisplay.Position := poMainFormCenter; 
  FormDisplay.Enabled := true;   // no modifica en absoluto el comportamiento
  FormDisplay.Visible := true;
  FormDisplay.Parent := nil; // no modifica en absoluto el comportamiento
  FormDisplay.SetFocus; // no modifica en absoluto el comportamiento
  FormDisplay.Show;
```

La unidad donde tengo TVCLFORM, es una unidad como todas con sus uses, y sus declaraciones nada mas :

```
procedure TFormVcl.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   case key of
    65: bLeft := True;
    83: bDown := True;
    87: bUp := True;
    68: bRight := True;
    VK_SPACE : bShot := True;
  end;


end;

// captura de eventos del teclado en formulario
procedure TFormVcl.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    case key of
    65: bLeft :=false;
    83: bDown := false;
    87: bUp := false;
    68: bRight := false;
    VK_SPACE :bShot := false;
  end;
end;
```

Al crearlo de esta forma de seguro hay algo que escapa a mi conocimiento, algo que tenga que ver con el foco, que ya lo he intentado, o con la captura de mensajes  de windows o eventos. Desconozco.

Al fin y al cabo la idea mas adelante es que la unidad detecte en que plataforma se encuentra y cree el formulario correspondiente, **VCL** en Windows, y **FMX** en android.
**Entiendo que FMX funciona en ambos, pero esto lo estoy realizando a manera de aprendizaje para determinar que tanta independencia puedo darle a mis unidades **

Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomiendo leer la primera parte de mi respuesta, pues hay varios conceptos relacionados que considero importante dominar para programar en Delphi. Sin embargo puedes saltar al final de la respuesta para encontrar la solución a tu problema.

## Eventos en Delphi

Comenzaré explicando algunas ideas detrás de los *eventos* en Delphi.

- Object Pascal soporta lo que se conoce como *tipos procedurales* [Procedural types](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Procedural_Types_(Delphi)) que, en resúmen, son variables que contienen un puntero a un fragmento de código ejecutable, por ejemplo, esto es válido en pascal:

  ```
    type
      TStrProc: procedure(const S: string);
    var
      MiVariableAProcedimiento: TStrProc;
    begin
      MiVariableAProcedimiento := @StrProc1;
      MiVariableAProcedimiento('hola');
      MiVariableAProcedimiento := @StrProc2;
      MiVariableAProcedimiento('hola otra vez');
    end;
  ```

  Los procedimientos `StrProc1` y `StrProc2` tienen que existir, su firma debe coincidir con la declaración del tipo y deben ser visibles al código de la asignación.
- Un tipo especial de estos es un *apuntador a método* (method pointer) que es un doble puntero que, además de apuntar al fragmento de código ejecutable, apunta también a una instancia de un objeto en memoria. Su declaración incluye las palabras `of object` al final de la declaración de tipo, así:

  ```
    type
      TNotifyEvent: procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
      TMiTipoDeMetodo: procedure(const S: string) of object;
  ```
- Un *evento* no es más que una propiedad de tipio *apuntador a método*.
- El método de una clase que se asocia a un evento se conoce como *manejador de evento*. Hay una linea algo fina aquí, pero debe quedar claro que el método no es el evento en si, sino el código que se ejecutará cuando se lance el evento.
- En tiempo de ejecución un evento puede estar asociado a un manejador particular o no estar asignado a ningún manejador. De hecho, la asociación se puede cambiar en cualquier momento, considera este caso:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ShowMessage('No hagas clic de nuevo!');
    Button1.OnClick := Button1NuevoClick;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Button1NuevoClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ShowMessage('No creí que te atrevieras, no haré nada más por ti');
    Button1.OnClick := nil;
  end;
  ```
- Cuándo estás diseñando un formulario o módulo de datos, cuando haces doble clic en el inspector de objetos ocurren dos cosas:

  - Se crea un *manejador de eventos* en la clase del formulario o módulo de datos que estás editando. Esto involucra la declaración del método en la declaración de clase, y su implementación. El cursor se coloca después del `begin` de dicha implementación.
  - Se *asocia* el evento en el componente que tienes seleccionado con dicho manejador de evento. Esta asociación queda registrada en el archivo *dfm* en el caso de VCL o *fmx* en el caso de FireMonkey.
- En tiempo de ejecución, cuando se crea una instancia de este formulario, el mecanismo de *streaming* resolverá la asociación entre el manejador de evento y el evento registrada en el DFM/FMX y realizará dicha asignación en las instancias correctas de los objetos. De esta forma podemos tener varias instancias de un formulario o módulo de datos, y no hay confusión en qué *objeto* es el que está relacionado cuando se lanza el evento como tal.
- Quiero resaltar en este punto que, si observas con detenimiento, el método asociado como manejador de evento no tiene por qué pertenecer al mismo objeto que publicó el evento. Esto ocurre todo el tiempo si, por ejemplo, botas un botón en el formulario, haces doble clic en él y se crea un manejador de evento en la clase del formulario, que es asociado al evento del botón.

Encontrarás más información en la documentación: [Eventos](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Events_(Delphi))

## Por qué no se lanzan los *eventos* en tu programa actual:

Dicho todo esto, lo que falta es realizar dicha asociación entre evento y manejador, que no es más que una asignación `:=`, por ejemplo, después de crear el formulario, faltaría agregar:

```
FormDisplay.OnKeyDown := FormDisplay.FormKeyDown;
FormDisplay.OnKeyUp := FormDisplay.FormKeyUp;
```

## Reflexiones adicionales

Dicho esto, si no quieres utilizar el DFM/FMX asociado al formulario porque quieres algo totalmente vacío, cuestionaría el por qué estás utilizando el editor de formularios para *diseñarlo*.

En realidad no hace falta, puedes declarar la clase en una unidad simple, sin DFM asociado y trabajar en ella sin el editor de formularios.

De hecho, puedes romper la asociación que hay entre el .pas y el .dfm eliminando la línea

```
{$R *.dfm}
```

Y luego puedes eliminar el archivo DFM completamente. Hecho esto, no podrás utilizar más el editor de formularios, pero entiendo que es lo que quieres.

Por otro lado, si no quieres llenar el código de asignaciones de manejadores de eventos, es perfectamente legal tener un formulario completamente vacío en el editor de formularios, y aprovechar los *poderes* del inspector de objetos para crear manejadores de eventos y que se asignen de manera automática en tiempo de ejecución. Para que esto ocurra, claro está, hay que llamar al constructor `Create` del formulario y dejar que haga su trabajo, pues eso permitirá tener un código más simple.

Comment: Voy por la 3 vez que leo y se que lo de los eventos lo desconozco. Y no hablar de punteros y menos punteros a métodos. Sin embargo tu aporte impecable como siempre. De hecho no utilize el dfm. Ni el diseñador de formularios . Lo realize a mano en una unit aparte. hace poco pude realizar otra pequeña mejora en el código haciendo esa asignación en el Create del Formulario. Pero es un tema que complejo ya que no lo pude entender bien. Pero reitero := impecable siempre que consulto algo de delphi tengo tu aporte .

Comment: Hace rato vengo practicando . Yo aprendí a programar con delphi . Y es un lenguaje que le tengo cariño. Últimamente ando incursionando en otros lenguajes y a medida que voy aprendiendo conceptos nuevos en otros lenguajes , lo practico también en delphi y lo entiendo más rápido. De hecho la consulta anterior que me la cerraron sobre Delphi y C# , sobre que ventajas podría llegar a tener pasandome a c# y utilizando .net  me hubiera gustado tener tu aporte puesto que pienso que llevas años con delphi . Cómo que me cuesta salir de delphi y pasarme a otros.

Comment: Delphi es muy cómodo para desktop y eso lo comprendo. Lo que me hace realmente dudar es que tan obsoleto está ... Si es que lo está, y que cosas se pueden hacer en otros lenguajes que delphi no haga. Se que la web no es lo mío. Me gusta más las tripas que no se ven. La otra vez me puse a intentar crear ventanas a pelo con win32 . Algo totalmente innecesario hoy en día. Pero que el ejecutable pesaba 200kb en vez de 100megas de los de c#. Me ayuda a entender mejor los conceptos.

Comment: Bueno, el concepto de punteros era, hace 30 años, de lo más básico que tenías que aprender. Cierto que a muchas personas les parecía complicado, aunque en realidad no lo és, pero lleva un esfuerzo mental adicional. Complicado no es y, como todo en la programación, si lo haces con orden y cuidado, resulta bien. Hoy por hoy, en lenguajes como c# o java no se visualizan como tal los punteros, aunque tras bambalinas todo se hace con ellos y muchas variables son _referencias_ que, al final, es lo mismo.

Comment: Sobre si es obsoleto, vamos, no entraré a esa discusión. Para mi, no lo es. Sigue vigente, actualizándose, y se puede hacer prácticamente lo que quieras, incluso en multi-plataforma. Dicho eso, yo suelo programar en varios lenguajes y me gusta conocer nuevos. Delphi me gusta más y tengo oportunidad de usarlo día a día, pero no siempre es así. He pasado meses o años más metido en c#, java, php, python y otros. Eso me permite también conocer y comparar las capacidades de cada uno y mi opinión, como ya he dicho, es que no es obsoleto.

Comment: Sobre la pregunta que te cerraron, no es apta para el formato del sitio y debió ser por eso, pero podemos charlar un día de estos en el chat, dónde si se puede.

Answer (score 1):

Lo termine solucionando asignando los eventos en tiempo de ejecución al momento de crearlos.
De cierta forma lo pude solucionar.
Pero esto me marea un poco en mi compresión .Aunque ahora podría prescindir de la unidad que cree para tal fin, con la clase **TFormVCL**, ya que no usa la implementación de los eventos que tiene.

Creacion en tiempo de ejecucion en unidad principal :

```
FormDisplay := TFormVcl.CreateNew(nil,0);
  FormDisplay.Parent := nil;
  FormDisplay.Width := xLimit;
  FormDisplay.Height := yLimit;
  FormDisplay.Position := poMainFormCenter;
  FormDisplay.OnKeyDown :=  OtraClase.FormKeyDown; //esto faltaba
```

Realize la implementación del procedimiento, ligado a otra clase(**TOtraClase**). Y luego se la asigne al evento onkeyDown, de la variable del formulario que cree en ejecucion. Esta parte es la que no me gusta. Porque aca el codigo se me empieza a enmarañar y me gustaría hacerlo de otra forma más simple,o mas elegante, pero
sinceramente la parte de **eventos** no la comprendo mucho.

Crei que funcionaria si los mismos ya estan implementados dentro de la clase TFormVCL , que esta en otra unit.

No se si tendrá que ver, con algo que leí en la documentación, de que el **CreateNew**, no inicializa los campos y demás.

Si alguien me puede aportar algo más de info. Y doy por cerrada.
Desde ya gracias.